# Why I can't create a database using CodeFirst on Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

I am following [this tutorial](http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/first-impressions-of-code-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/) to learn how to use Code First (CF) with Entity Frame Visual Studio 2012. Unfortunately, I don't know why I can't create a database using LocalDB on VS2012. I already defined the ConnectionString in the App.Config file as following:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--To connect to the localDB-->
    <add name="HealthTracker" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HealthTrackerDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I used this command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Database -ProjectName HealthTracker.DataAccess -Verbose -Force
```

I got the following error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I don't know why I am getting this error while I am not using master database. All what I want is creating a new database called HealthTrackerDB using LocalDB in VS 2012 as shown in the tutorial.

**So how can I fix this problem?**

Comment: It seems like this is an authorization problem. Normally, when a database is created, you execute this DML statement against the master database in case you use a MS SQL database. Can you use SQL Server Management Studio to access your LocalDB and try to create a database using it? You can download it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using an .mdf file if you're just trying out a sample. I have a blog post with step-by-step instructions, a working sample, and how to resolve common issues.

http://wakeupandcode.com/entity-framework-code-first-migrations/

Hope this helps!